# Error: "Node - No such file or directory" while using Sass compiler in Netbeans

Tags: node.js, sass, netbeans

I configured sass to be used in Netbeans, to compile sass files on save. Netbeans is displaying this command (one line, quotes included):
`"/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.0/bin/sass" "/full/path/to/sass/file.scss" "/full/path/to/css/file.css"`

And returns this error:
`"/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory"`

**When I run the exact command directly in the terminal, the compilation works without errors.**

How could I fix the problem inside Netbeans, so it would be able to properly use the sass compiler directly?

----- System information -----
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS 
Apache NetBeans IDE 18 (with all the needed settings that worked with Ruby Sass) 
sass --version = 1.64.1 compiled with dart2js 3.0.6 
node --version = v18.17.0

Comment: FWIW I've reported the issue https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/7095

Comment: @JasperdeVries, not really a solution, but a workaround: I run the SASS compiler in a command line, separate of NetBeans - eg. sass --watch src/sass/child-theme.scss:css/child-theme.css => this solves the main problem of converting the scss file to css, but I need to adapt and run this command in the right folder each time I work on such a project. In NetBeans I still get the error about the conversion (if I still enable the conversion in the specific project - there is not much use for this).